# pop up window when message selected in other app - Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, dictionary, popup

Is it possible to pop up a window for a selected text within another android app ?

for example a user is using some pdf reader and selects a word and a small window pops up that provides the options to highlight the text or Define and ... , I want to know is it possible to add another option to that window (or add a small window next to that) that defines the meaning using my dictionary app, not the pdf reader's dictionary?

basically I want to know if it is possible to have the user to use my dictionary app for all his needs , surfing web, reading pdf , looking up words directly ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible.

Only way of do that if you upload your app to Google Play and shared the options with other apps (using PendingIntents and Broadcast actions), but the code of other apps must use your code, you can not modify other app installed.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then NO.

It is not possible to edit the behavior of other apps with your own since then you would have to edit that apps source code. As far as I know the system does not provide any overhead setting for what your asking as it does for sharing things whith different apps (email, social media etc.)